# PMD Class definition inside method

Tags: warnings, pmd

I use a local class inside a method and PMD triggers 2 warnings headerCommentRequirement for the class and publicMethodCommentRequirement for a method inside a class, I write the comments on both  as if it was a normal class but it doesn't work. Any ideas on this? Thanks for you help.
The code looks like this:

```
/**
* 
* @author me
*
*/
class myClass{
    void thisMethod(){
        if(condition){

            /**
            * 
            * @author me
            * This is the local class
            */
            class localClass implements otherClass{

                /**
                * Method comment
                */              
                public boolean boolMethod(){
                    //Do Something
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it using //NOPMD (which ignores the PMD warning) on the local class line, as it wasn't my class and PMD didn't recognize the comment. It is the only solution I got.

```
class LocalClass implements OtherClass{ //NOPMD

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Correct javadoc should have second and following lines indented by addtional space, and the description should be before any tags:

```
/**
 * Description.
 * @author me
 */
```

Comment: No luck, PMD is crazy

Comment: you also need to document `thisMethod`